# Building a DOS-feel script. How to make the command line?

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

I always had the idea to make a textarea based program, that gets the last line and uses it as a command. So it looks like some cool DOS-like program.. But in fact is simple textarea -> AJAX -> PHP -> textarea again. Textarea based version works great, but has alot of drawbacks. Mostly related to not getting the right command and possible vulnerabilities to the script.

So, my idea is to use a output container and command line totally separately. I found **[a good example of what I want](http://www.workvsplay.com/code/dos/main.aspx)**, but I cannot figure out, how it is actually made. The main idea is that the hole thing feels like one block of text and you can highlight it:

[image]

But you actually cant delete the prompt (c:>) or the already outputted text above.. Since the command line is an actual input.

I don't understand, how this effect is being achieved. You can see the above examples source code, it is basically:

```
<div id="black_wrapper">
    <div id="outputted_code"></div>
    <span id="prompt">c:\&gt;</span><span id="commandline"></span><span id="blinker"></span>
    <input type="text" name="actual_commandline" value="" />
</div>
```

And the JavaScript behind it is: http://pastebin.com/pjbd9Y7k

**How can I merge the spans line with the input, so it works like one line, but you cannot manipulate the `span#prompt` or `span#blinker` contents?**

It is very hard to find any help on www for such localized problems. I can see some CSS in the example-link above..however my knowledge of CSS tells me, that it has nothing to do with that layout.

Also, I drew out exactly what I'm thinking to do, as it is very hard to explain these types of technical questions:

[image]

- Red = General wrapper, not much function
- Blue = Prompt area, very static
- Green = Writing area, expands its width when typing, pushing the blinker more to the right
- Purple = Blinker container, simple gif animation that looks like this: [image]

**Note:** I'm not actually ripping-off that example site, but well only that command-line layout. Any hint, link code or idea is welcome. It can be totally alternative, but should achieve the goal, thanks :)

**Edit:** The question got solved thanks to Joe. However, since the original idea might interest somebody in the future.. I will include a small picture, of what my script looks like. Maybe this inspires some of you someday :)

[image]

Comment: Eww, why DOS? If you're going to emulate a prompt, do *nix style...

Comment: @tjameson I used `C:\>` for this question, because of the example-link. My own script uses something totally different, but the command-line layout should still be the same.

Comment: I don't think the words 'DOS' and 'cool' should be used in the same sentence. Why do you think Windows happened in the first place?

Comment: @ClarkeyBoy: However, "AJAX" and "DOS-lookalike" = cool. The example-link script is very COOL fyi. You cannot make a geekier homepage, then that. However, it is lacking all sort of practical use. Im building something totally different, but I cant figure out, how the command-line is being made :(

Comment: Yes you're right - there is nothing geekier! :D I think Joe is correct; he is basically using an absolutely positioned div and repositioning it every time you press the enter key; the cursor, I suspect, is another absolutely positioned span which is moved on every key press. You could use it for all sorts of weird and wonderful stuff - displaying a list of files in a directory and just appending the text that the user enters to the end of the current directory whenever they press enter. You then just called `$("#myDiv").load("/filelist.aspx?directory=blah");`, or something similar.

Comment: @Clark That was my first thought too. But I couldn't find the keypoints, where he is manipulating with the actual input-field. And the backend isn't the problem :) My script works and is much much more dynamic then that example, but it was based on single textarea.. Which will limit the possibilities, especially with the chat-feature.

Comment: Why go to the hassle of re-positioning it? Set a `position: relative` and `left: -300px` and the `top` will take care of itself automatically :) Kalle - keypoints? How do you mean?

Comment: @Joe, sorry for my bad terms. I currently have a fewer. I basically meant the lines of codes. But I do understand completely now. It actually makes perfect sense now and I feel pretty stupid, as the left: -300px; was sitting right in front of me for 3 hours.. But I guess the fewer does its job. Anyways thanks man, I think there is no better solution for this, without losing browser-compatibility.

Comment: ...fffffffffffffffffuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu that gave me a shock when I just scrolled up and saw something weird with a ghostly looking person haha xD

Comment: @Joe: Yup, my friend in negative-fade :D But I think the [original picture](http://a4.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc6/262747_234004413291429_100000456160972_885580_4966244_n.jpg) is even more scarier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What he's doing is hiding a textbox off-screen. The actual command line is just an element styled to have 1 line's worth of height. When you click this command line, the textbox takes focus.

The `C:\>` and `_` sandwich the textarea, so your text appears in between, thus increasing the `width` on the command line element as you type, and pushing the `_` to the right, giving the illusion that it moved on its own.

http://jsfiddle.net/YeR3L/1/

Comment: I was wondering that, but I couldn't find the line, where the textbox is being hidden.

Comment: Search the source for "entryBox". It gets shifted -300px to the left off-screen using CSS to hide it.

Comment: I see. However, is that the most optimized solution, negative margin? Cant i make the field invisible somehow, or the field-blinker will still be visible? Or maybe a div-container that is writable?

Comment: @Kalle H. Väravas Updated it, to show the "pushing down" being done automatically. http://jsfiddle.net/YeR3L/1/ - now that's your lot :P

Comment: Oh yes, of course. Thanks by the way, this really nerfs my workload :) I tweaked it a little, since it was very hard to click on the right thing and since the hole window will be the "dos"-window..then wherever you click, it focus on the right input: http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/YeR3L/2/ So yeah, this question is more then solved. For trivial purposes I added a screenshot of my script :D

Comment: Just in case you didn't see it, there's a better version of it, see the main answer for the link :) You probably have, but better to be sure :)

Comment: I saw, that part is basically the same already in my script :) But as for your answers quality, its pretty sick how much code you did. So thanks man!